# Recognize async methods in android

Tags: android, asynchronous

In android some methods are called async (and from the UI-thread) 
for example:

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
                    // doSomething
                }
            });
```

is called async

How do I generelly recognize if I have a method that will called async?

How do I generelly recognize if I have a method that will called from UI-thread?

Comment: `is called async` ? What exactly is called async in your example? I see nothing asynchronous.

Comment: Usually if you're passing in a callback that will be an asynchronous operation.  The best thing is if there is documentation that makes it explicit.  Failing that, if you really need to know you'll have to look at the source code and see if it starts a new thread or uses AsyncTask.

Comment: Thank you, i've hoped there is an easier way